# References, Logical Operators, and Loop Condition

Tags: c++, reference, do-while, ternary-operator

I'm having a problem understanding what I'm doing wrong in my code. What I'm trying to do is write a condition for a ternary operator and a do-while loop to recognize if one of my variables is above 1. Well, it is giving me an error that I don't know how to fix. What puzzles me the most is what I'll give an example of shortly. Here's my overall code. Keep in mind I'm a beginner, so there may be things that make you cringe or parts that could be improved.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getInfo(int&, int&, double&);

int main() {

   int ordered, stock;
   double charges = 10.00;

   getInfo(ordered, stock, charges);

   system("pause");
   return 0;

}

void getInfo(int& ordered, int& stock, double& charges) {

   do {
       printf("Enter the amount of spools ordered, in stock, and handling charges: ");
       scanf_s("%i %i %lf", &ordered, &stock, &charges);

       printf((&ordered > 1 && &stock > 0 && &charges > 0) ? "All added!\n"
           : "You messed one up. AGAIN!\n");
   } while (&ordered > 1 && &stock > 0 && &charges > 0);

}
```

Now, the error I'm getting is specifically in the ternary and the while condition. It gives me an error where the `>` is after ordered for both. Now, if I make it `ordered` instead of `&ordered`, the error goes away. Yet, I never get an error for `&stock` or `&charges`. I don't know why it's treating `&ordered` differently. It also doesn't check `ordered` correctly when I take off the `&`, for reasons I'm not entirely sure on.

Thank you to whomever is willing to help!

Comment: You might want to read up on what `&` means in different contexts. Hint: `&ordered` isn't doing what you seem to expect  inside the ternary expression. If you were to compile your code with warnings enables you might have gotten an error like `ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]` (depending on what compiler you use).

Comment: @jpw Trust me, I've tried.. Am I at least on the right track you think? I imagine you know what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: I use Visual Studio. It tells me on both lines that there is no conversion from int to int*.. But I'm not sure what that means. Also, the error goes away if I make the 1 a zero. Not sure why it does that, either...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @user2475059
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2446 '>': no conversion from 'int' to 'int *' ch6ex14 c:\users\kaykay\desktop\ch6ex14\ch6ex14\ch6ex14.cpp 24

Comment: It would seem that your are on the right track. Try removing the ampersand from the variables inside the printf statement and the while condition and see what happens.

Comment: The issue is that you are using `&` to take the address of a variable (and thus getting a pointer) when you really want to use the value (which does not require &)

Comment: What you are trying to do is compare `&ordered`, a pointer to `int` or `int *`, with literal 1, an `int`, ergo the error message. All I can do here is echo @jpw 's advice that you read up on all the fun things `&` does.

Comment: @jpw
When I do that, it doesn't loop again through the do-while again, yet it does print the correct string in the ternary.

Comment: Also consider using `std::cin` for input rather than `scanf_s`. Either way, test the return from the reads to make sure you really read  what you expected. Some instructors just loooove typing in stuff like "fubar" where you expected a number and grade accordingly.

Comment: Do you want it to keep looping? The way you wrote it suggests that not infinite looping was what you wanted, so it seems like it's doing what you want now.

Comment: @user2475059

I want it to loop through the do-while if even one of the numbers is below what I want them to be. Ordered being 1, while stock and charges is 0.

Comment: Then not having `&` is what you want. If it prints "all added", then it should exit the loop, since it's the same condition in both places.

Comment: @user2475059 I took the & off of all of them, and the printf works! The while doesn't, however. It prints what it's supposed to, but then still exits the loop.

Comment: @user2475059 I figured it out! I was using the wrong logical operator... whoops. :> Was supposed to use ||. Thank you for your help! I'm gonna read up on * and & some more. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 1):

```
...(&ordered > 1 && &stock > 0 && &charges > 0) ? "All added!\n"
```

Here, "&ordered" means "the address of the `ordered` variable. You're obviously not trying to compare the address of `ordered`, but rather `ordered` itself. This should be

```
...(ordered > 1 && stock > 0 && charges > 0) ? "All added!\n"
```

The same problem is with your while() statement too.

In C++, "&" means two things. In declarations, it's used to declare a reference. In expression, it's the "address of" operator.

Once you declare a reference, like:

```
int &whatever;
```

Subsequently, using just `whatever` refers to the referenced object itself.

```
       : "You messed one up. AGAIN!\n");
```

Comment: After having everyone point out that I was using them wrong, I think it'll stick in my head this time how to use & haha. Now I just need to learn how to use *. Thank you @Sam Varshavchik!

Comment: Might want to edit and add the third `&` thing: bitwise and. Not relevant here, but for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator does different things depending on where you put it.  If it's in a type declaration (e.g. `int& foo`), it means that the type is a *reference*.  If however the `&` is used as an unary operator in an expression it becomes the *Address-of* operator, and returns a pointer to the object it's used on.  So for example `int* bar = &spam` (assuming `spam` is an integer) would assign a pointer to spam in in the pointer bar.

Note that reference types behaves identical to the real type.  This is perhaps better illustrated with a piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int foo = 12;
    int& bar = foo;  // a reference expects a variable of the same type in the initializer
    bar = 24; // Once the reference has been made the variable behaves indentically to the
              // to the variable it's a reference to.
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;  // outputs 24

    // if you use the & operator on a reference you get the address the variable it is a
    // reference to.
    std::cout << &bar << ' ' << &foo << std::endl; // Outputs two equal addresses.
}
```

There is also a third meaning of `&` in C++.  As the bitwise and operator.  `foo & bar` would result in the bitwise and of the variable `foo` and `bar`.